# How can I create html files using by ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net

First of all, I have a project, and I have a question.

I created asp.net form like:

```
Name: 
Surname:
Grade: 
Last comments: 

submit - reset
```

How can I create new html file like which fills that form and submits it. I want to create a new html file, `example.html`, and I just want to this html file include all things. Like:

```
example.html

Name:  alp
surname: ozkan
grade: 100
Last comments :  optional.
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I think you should really go and read up about how ASP.NET works...

Comment: I think , i did not meant myself. I have a form and i want to create html files on using that form.

Comment: So you want to generate a HTML page from your posted information? Are you sure you just don't want to display a HTML page to the user with the posted information?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question otherwise, you won't get anywhere. You have a form that is meant to be filled out, and you need to show what the user filled? _If that is your intent_, listen to @James because that is pretty basic in ASP.Net or any platform for that matter (including client side - Javascript). Otherwise, as stated, please clarify your question, and perhaps show what you have tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("<html>");
str.Append("<head>");
str.Append("<title>This is simple header</title>");
str.Append("</head>");
str.Append("<body>");
str.Append("Your content from asp.net form append here");
str.Append("</body>");
str.Append("</html>");

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\path\\myFile.html");
writer.Write(str.ToString());
writer.Close();

Response.Write("File was created");
```

it will generate html or any other file

Comment: thank you @gogagubi . I did not get it how this could be easy :)

Comment: Have a look also at nvelocity. It's a really nice tempering engine.